# Exception has occurred: Execute Error ERROR 000622: Parameters are not valid ERROR 000628: Cannot set input into parameter Coordinate_System

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, geometry, error-000628, error-000622

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Keep getting this error:

> Exception has occurred: Execute Error ERROR 000622: Parameters are not
> valid ERROR 000628: Cannot set input into parameter Coordinate_System

Code:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"C:\PSP\WeeklyWork\Week10\ArcPyAutomation\AutomationData\CANADA"

in_features = "lakes.shp"

properties = "PERIMETER_LENGTH_GEODESIC"

length_unit = "KILOMETERS"

coordinate_system = arcpy.SpatialReference("Projected Coordinate 
System/Continental/North America/Canada_Lambert_Conformal_Conic")

arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management(in_features, properties, length_unit, "", coordinate_system)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are calling the SpatialReference incorrectly. Try doing it either as:

Just the code:

```
arcpy.SpatialReference(102002)
```

or just the name:

```
arcpy.SpatialReference("Canada_Lambert_Conformal_Conic")
```

or the filepath to a PRJ ensuring you include the extension:

```
arcpy.SpatialReference("C:\\My_Coords_Folder\\Canada_Lambert_Conformal_Conic.prj")
```

Refs: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/spatialreference.htm
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/pdf/projected_coordinate_systems.pdf